# Are split cv boots any good?

Tags: cv-joint

If you have a leaking cv boot there are these split cv boots you can use to replace them.  you can basically wrap the cv boot around and glue it together without disassembling the wheel, axle etc then you just glue the sides of the boot together.

This would seem very convenient however they don't seem to be popular with mechanics.

Are these any good/should I use them or do you not recommend them and if so why?

Comment: The "convenience" is balanced against the fact that you probably can't replace the lost grease, and you don't know what contaminants have got inside the leaking boot. But I suppose if you plan to sell the car the day after you did the repair, and the buyer is too clueless to notice them, they might have some value ;)

Comment: I used one, replaced the grease and it was fine - depends a lot on who does the job - someone who knows or someone who rushes and does not know....

Comment: It's a bandaid not a permanent fix

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not any good.

I once had a car with cracked rubber in the CV boot. It was replaced by a mechanic, and they replaced the grease as well. However, the repair didn't last the test of time and the thing that held the CV boot in place cracked in half after few years of use. So, I then repaired with a zip tie temporarily and drove the car to a garage to do welding of unrelated rust damage and full CV boot repair.

When I got the car back, they said they fixed everything. I believed them, wrongly so! They apparently thought that because of the zip tie, the CV boot was already repaired and didn't need repairing. So, the end result was that after few months I started to hear noises from the CV joint. Then I looked at the CV boot and yep, the zip tie was still in place! They didn't repair it with new grease! The temporary repair I did was still there.

If you use these split CV boots, you will have the same troubles I had: contaminants get inside, and if the grease is not changed, the CV joint will fail.

Comment: Nothing like checking what work has been done - the garage I use are more than happy to put the car on the ramp for 2 minutes just to show exactly what and where has been worked on / replaced and show off their work - makes the bill slightly less painful when you have seen they did what they said.

Answer (score 1):

I've used them maybe three times. Not had one (or the shaft they were on) fail in service.

I cleaned the bulk of the old grease off but didn't wash the joint with solvent.

This is sometimes recommended, sometimes deprecated, so I dunno about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had good luck with them many years ago. Back when rebuild axles were not available, a new axle was several hundred dollars. The split boots were about 1/10th cost and came with a container of grease. I only used them on CV joints that had small tears that seemed recent. The quality of the repair and its durability are directly proportional to the quality of the installation. For the seam to seal it has to be meticulously clean. Not an easy task as the assembly is covered in grease. If the boot is shredded and been contaminated I would just use a rebuilt axle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why people act as if they can't clean the CV joint of containments?  It's not that difficult.  Just use degreaser and reapply grease. 
I certainly would not replace one simply because it's contaminated.

"The "convenience" is balanced against the fact that you probably can't replace the lost grease, and you don't know what contaminants have got inside the leaking boot."
Why can't you replace the lost grease?  You do realize that you take the old boot off to install the new one. 
It's like a couple of people said the results depend on the quality of the install.

Comment: If the contamination has been in there long, it might damage bearing surfaces.  Some CV boots are easier than others.  If you need that special spreading tool to get it over flanges or whatever, that price plus the price of replacement boots usually far exceeds the cost of a good reman halfshaft.

Answer (score 0):

I've had mixed results (mostly due to inexperience and the first two I installed failed).  As mentioned in previous posts, the trick is to get the boot on and glued together without getting grease into the boot seams before you glue.  The third time I did it I removed the old boot, cleaned the joint with brake parts cleaner and wiped everything clean.  I had glued one side of the new boot assemble the night before.  I installed the new boot over the axle, pushed it down the axle away from the CV joint and glued the second seam.  While it was curing I applied the new grease to the joint with a flat wood spatula.  Cleaned up the edges and pulled the new boot up and over the joint outer housing, clamped in place on both ends.  **TIP** I found it easier on my car to work on assembling the boot, greasing the joint, and putting the boot in place from above the wheel.  I only had to crawl under the car to adjust the position of the boot and tighten the clamps.  Total work time was 1-hr from start to finish.

Answer (score -1):

My van is 20 years old. European regulations now require the CV joint covers to be undamaged to pass the biannual 'EU' test in Norway. I had my joint covers fixed at the workshop at a cost of NOK3100 (about 300 euro). 2 years later I went for a control - and they are rotten. The workshop is refusing that it is their responsibility. I will be taking the simpler option and gluing covers on this time. Plenty of good youtube tutorials out there. Last word is not spoken regaring responsibility with the workshop...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63988)